# Add some small amount of flexibility in the plural tag creation rule to allow users to fix newly-created tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, plurals

A [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50772/were-tina-fey-and-john-cena-digitally-enhanced-in-sisters-2015) was recently asked (nine hours ago from time of writing) on Movies.SE about the Tina Fey film *Sisters*. A well-meaning user created a tag for the film as this was the first question asked about it on the site. Unfortunately, when they created the tag, they created "[sister](/questions/tagged/sister)" instead of "[sisters](/questions/tagged/sisters)".

I noticed the error and attempted to change it but was prevented from creating the new tag due to the plural versions of existing tags rule.

This is a **great** rule. I **do not** want to get rid of it.

What I would like is to see if it's at all possible - in the case of single-question and/or newly-created (last 24 hours) tags - to *relax* this rule a bit so that bad tags can be fixed. This issue shouldn't require a mod and a meta post to rectify.

I would be willing to consider this as something limited to a certain group of users, say 5K as part of the "approve tag wiki edits" or 2.5K as part of the "create tag synonyms".

---

*As a note, I have currently deleted the incorrect tag from the question so that it will be purged eventually (whenever that happens), so don't expect to see it on the question. You can see that it was created for the question by viewing the edit history.

Comment: If only a few questions are affected, remove the tag from all questions (remember which they were), wait 24 hours for it to be deleted and then add the right tag to the questions.

Comment: Yes, that's a solution... but it's not a very good one because you have a question sitting around without the proper tag (or in some cases, potentially, no tags) until either a mod fixes it or the tag gets purged. Regardless, in this case, that's what I've already done... which I had just added to the question when you commented.