# Tweaking the name of a new tag on the question defining it is not possible

Tags: bug, tags

If you write a question adding a new tag `footag`, then try to edit the question, to change this tag to `footags`, you will get an error message about `footag` already existing, and be referred to meta to suggest the new tag be created. However, `footag` exists only on this question, so the change should be legit without any further discussion - you are just changing your mind about the tag name.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277403/284336